# How to Retrieve data from Pivot table in Laravel using Datatables

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, datatables, pivot

I'm trying to retrieve data from Pivot table using Yajra Datatables.

Model Project.php

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','client_id', 'name','description', 'projectType','service_id','files','startDate','endDate','progress','status'];

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

Model Employee.php

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'surname','address','tel', 'email','profession'];

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project');
    }
}
```

Model EmployeeProject.php

```
class EmployeeProject extends Pivot
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'employee_id', 'project_id'];
}
```

ProjectsController.php

```
$projects = Project::with('employee');
return Datatables::of($projects)
->make(true);
```

projects.blade.php

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "paging":   false,
                "ajax": "{{ route('projects.getdata') }}",
                "order": [[1,'desc']],
                "columns": [    
                {"data": "id"},     
                {"data": "client_id"},
                {"data": "name"},
                {"data": "description"},
                {"data": "projectType"},
                {"data": "service_id"},               
                {"data": "employees.name"}, - **I need to retrieve the names of the employees who are involved in the project**
                {"data": "files"},
                {"data": "startDate"},
                {"data": "endDate"},
                {"data": "progress", orderable:false, searchable: false},
                {"data": "status"},
```

Let you know that I'm using pivot table employee_project to link tables (employees and projects). The creating function is working good because the records being added to the pivot table correctly.
The problem is that I need to dipslay the name of all employees that are involved in the project like:

```
id| name | employeeName  |...|
-----------------------------
1 | test | John, Mark,...|...|
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use implode to save data like comma saparete.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this:

in projects.blade.php

```
{
  data: function (row) {
   let employeeNames= [];
     $(row.employee).each(function (i, e) {
       employeeNames.push(e.name);
       });
     return employeeNames.join(", ")
   }, name: 'employee.name'
},
```